# Blog search up to firebase data fetch in public

Tags: firebase, blogger

I have fetched data publicly to my blog from firebase database.

I wonder if this kind of thing could be done:

> During search in blog, is it can bind together with the firebase fetched data? If it is can be done...then marvellous!

Thanks!

---

Extra info:

This is my [sample](http://tukangurutdayang.blogspot.my/2016/12/senarai-pelanggan.html) blog.

As you can see, the list was fetched from firebase. I would like to let the user able to search on that list also.

The search area was at `Cari` area at the right top div.

Here..I tried to search something like this:

[image]

Comment: Please refine the question

Comment: @Mike76 see my updated question.